# Force service instantiation in Angular 2 sub-module (an alternative to AngularJS run block)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have a service in sub-module that wraps some third-party module, instantiates and initializes its service to prepare for use within app.

```
@Injectable()
class SubmoduleInitializerService {
    constructor (thirdPartyService: ThirdPartyService) {
      thirdPartyService.initialize(...);
      ...
    }
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [ThirdPartyModule],
    exports: [ThirdPartyModule],
    providers: [
        ThirdPartyService,
        SubmoduleInitializerService
    ]
})
class AppSubmodule {}
```

`ThirdPartyService` isn't injected in app directly but is used by other `ThirdPartyModule` units, so as long as `SubmoduleInitializerService` is injected in the same injector as `ThirdPartyService` or parent injector, everything is fine:

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(
      /* DO NOT REMOVE! BAD THINGS HAPPEN! */
      submoduleInitializerService: SubmoduleInitializerService
    ) {}
    ...
}
```

It was proven to be a lousy pattern because it is not obvious why `SubmoduleInitializerService` should stay injected in `AppComponent` if it's not used neither in class nor in template (was accidentally removed once already).

Basically `AppSubmodule` module needs an alternative to Angular 1.x `angular.module(...).run(...)` block.

What are the options here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`APP_INITIALIZER`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/APP_INITIALIZER-let.html) (undocumented) service plays the role of AngularJS config/run blocks reasonably well in Angular 2 (not counting the feature of asynchronous initialization).

For noop intialization block that just eagerly instantiates `SubmoduleInitializerService` it is:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ThirdPartyModule],
    exports: [ThirdPartyModule],
    providers: [
        ThirdPartyService,
        SubmoduleInitializerService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: () => () => {},
            deps: [SubmoduleInitializerService],
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
class AppSubmodule {}
```

Since `APP_INITIALIZER` is multi-provider, it allows to have several initialization functions per application that follow the order in which the modules are being loaded.

For synchronous initialization the shorter (and probably more appropriate) alternative is to inject the service into module's constructor:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ThirdPartyModule],
    exports: [ThirdPartyModule],
    providers: [
        ThirdPartyService,
        SubmoduleInitializerService
    ]
})
class AppSubmodule {
    constructor(sis: SubmoduleInitializerService) {}
}
```

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43827191/3731501), `APP_INITIALIZER` shares some traits with `config` block, too, because it is used to configure services prior to component initialization and is susceptible to race conditions (for example, since `APP_INITIALIZER` is used to configure `Router`, injecting it into another `APP_INITIALIZER` will result in circular dependency).

Comment: constructor approach worked for me when I had a service that was totally decoupled from the app.  Nothing talked to it directly.  It just registered listeners with a "store" service that would notify it when requests had been made, and it would respond and pass back its own messages with return values.  Thanks!